# how does Mongodb index works?

Tags: mongodb, indexing

```
I have a collection such as:
{u'_id': ObjectId('5094cc44e3f0f827b3618918'),
  u'xxx': 0},
 {u'_id': ObjectId('5094cc44e3f0f827b3618919'),
  u'xxx': 1},
 {u'_id': ObjectId('5094cc44e3f0f827b361891a'),
  u'xxx': 2},
 {u'_id': ObjectId('5094cc44e3f0f827b361891b'),
  u'xxx': 3},
 {u'_id': ObjectId('5094cc44e3f0f827b361891c'),
  u'xxx': 4}
...
```

when I create index such as:

```
db.test.ensure_index([("_id",-1),("xxx",1)])
db.test.ensure_index([("xxx",1)])
```

then,I use the explain such as:

```
db.test.find({"xxx":1}).sort("_id",-1).skip(5).limit(5).explain()

result is:
{u'allPlans': [{u'cursor': u'BtreeCursor _id_ reverse',
                u'indexBounds': {u'_id': [[{u'$maxElement': 1},
                                           {u'$minElement': 1}]]},
                u'n': 9,
                u'nscanned': 34,
               u'nscannedObjects': 34},
               {u'cursor': u'BtreeCursor xxx_1',
                u'indexBounds': {u'xxx': [[1, 1]]},
                u'n': 34,
                u'nscanned': 34,
                u'nscannedObjects': 34},
               {u'cursor': u'BtreeCursor _id_-1_xxx_1',
                u'indexBounds': {u'_id': [[{u'$maxElement': 1},
                                           {u'$minElement': 1}]],
                                 u'xxx': [[1, 1]]},
                u'n': 10,
                u'nscanned': 38,
                u'nscannedObjects': 10},
               {u'cursor': u'BasicCursor',
                u'indexBounds': {},
                u'n': 16,
                u'nscanned': 34,
                u'nscannedObjects': 34}],
 u'cursor': u'BtreeCursor xxx_1',
 u'indexBounds': {u'xxx': [[1, 1]]},
 u'indexOnly': False,
 u'isMultiKey': False,
 u'millis': 1,
 u'n': 5,
 u'nChunkSkips': 0,
 u'nYields': 0,
 u'nscanned': 34,
 u'nscannedAllPlans': 140,
 u'nscannedObjects': 34,
 u'nscannedObjectsAllPlans': 112,
 u'scanAndOrder': True,
 u'server': u'ubuntu:27017'}
```

from n,nscanned and nscnnedObjects 's num,I think It should use u'BtreeCursor *id*-1_xxx_1' as cursor,but Why It use u'cursor': u'BtreeCursor xxx_1',?
    Can anyone give me some suggestion ?I have a little knowledge about the index optimize.

Comment: It would help if you provided examples in javascript (the official mongo shell language).

Comment: That is a python language.I just want to know,when I use find('xxx').sort('_id',-1),How can I create an index ?

Comment: Put a field that you want to sort on in the end of index definition: `db.test.ensureIndex({xxx: 1, _id: -1})`

Comment: thanks for that,I have try it and the solution is ok.But I have some question:In <Mongodb:The Definitive Guide>,there is a suggestion to:use {'xxx':-1,'_id':1},so we can keep the latest update document in memory.But it seems not good for here.Any thing I wrong for understand this?

Comment: The sort order(1 or -1) must be the same as the index order(1 or -1) so that the sort can benefit from that index. If you create a index `p:1` and sort with `p:-1`, it won't use that index.

Comment: What's up with these `u` characters at start of each key? Am I missing something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The order of fields in the index matters; the best compound index for your find and sort example would actually be:

```
db.test.ensure_index([("xxx",1),("_id",-1)])
```

Since your search criteria is on field 'xxx', putting this field first in the index will find more results than searching by `_id` and then filtering to documents matching your `xxx` criteria.

If you look at the `n` number for each plan considered by the query optimizer in `allPlans`, the `BtreeCursor xxx_1` index actually returns the most results (34).  The other indexes return 9, 10, and 16 results .. so would be less efficient for the given search criteria.

For more information on index optimization, this article is very helpful: [Optimizing MongoDB Compound Indexes](http://java.dzone.com/articles/optimizing-mongodb-compound).