# how does Joint index work in mongodb?

Tags: mongodb, indexing, mongodb-indexes

In this question's comments, I know how to create index for sort operation: [how does Mongodb index works?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13207835/how-does-mongodb-index-works)

1. But I want to know, when we create a joint index on `a` & `b`, how does it work different  to a  simple index?
2. And why will we benefit in just finding `a`, but if we find `b`, we do not get any benefit from it? Whether joint index is just like concatenating `a` & `b`, so we will get benefit from it for Prefix?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> 1.But I want to know ,when we create an joint index on 'a'&'b',how does it work difference with an simple index?

MongoDB only uses a single index per query .. so if your `find()` criteria includes both `a` and `b` values, you should add a compound index to efficiently search both fields.

> 2.And why we will benifit just find 'a' but if we find 'b' ,we will do not get any benifit from it? whether joint index just like concatenate 'a'&'b' so we will get benifit from it for Prefix？

MongoDB uses [B-tree indexes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B-tree), so you can only efficiently match partial keys using a prefix. To find all possible values matching a suffix or substring, all index entries would have to be checked.

#### Set up test data to compare

Examples below are using the `mongo` shell:

```
/* Generate some test data */
for (i = 0; i< 1000; i++) {
    db.mycoll.insert({a:i})
    db.mycoll.insert({b:i})
    db.mycoll.insert({a:i,b:i})
}
```

Now add some sample indexes:

```
/* Add simple and compound index */
db.mycoll.ensureIndex({a:1})
db.mycoll.ensureIndex({b:1})
db.mycoll.ensureIndex({a:1, b:1})
```

Finally, for the test scenarios below force your query to use a specific index with [`$hint`](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Optimization#Optimization-Hint) and compare the [`explain()`](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Explain) results.

#### Search for `b` using simple index

A search for `b` using the simple index on `b` can find matching entries directly in the index .. it scans 4 index entries (`nscanned`) to return 4 results (`n`):

```
db.mycoll.find({b:10}).hint({b:1}).explain()
{
    "cursor" : "BtreeCursor b_1",
    "n" : 4,
    "nscannedObjects" : 4,
    "nscanned" : 4,
    ...
}
```

#### Search for `b` using compound index `(a,b)`

A search for `b` using the compound index on `(a,b)` has to check every `a` value in the index, because the first part of the index is the key value of `a`.

So to find matching entries directly in the index .. it scans **1904** index entries (`nscanned`) to return 4 results (`n`):

```
db.mycoll.find({b:10}).hint({a:1,b:1}).explain()
{
    "cursor" : "BtreeCursor a_1_b_1",
    "n" : 4,
    "nscannedObjects" : 4,
    "nscanned" : 1904,
    ...
}
```

Technically scanning 1,904 documents is less than the 3,000 total in my test collection .. but this is far from optimal.

#### Search for `a` using compound index `(a,b)`

For comparison, a search of `a` using the compound index shows that only 4 values need to be scanned to return 4 documents:

```
db.mycoll.find({a:10}).hint({a:1,b:1}).explain()
{
    "cursor" : "BtreeCursor a_1_b_1",
    "n" : 4,
    "nscannedObjects" : 4,
    "nscanned" : 4,
    "nscannedObjectsAllPlans" : 4,
    ...
}
```

For some further examples and explanation, I would recommend reading the article [Optimizing MongoDB Compound Indexes](http://java.dzone.com/articles/optimizing-mongodb-compound).